# Add ReportViewer control in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 C++. So, how can I add a ReportViewer control in Visual Studio 2022 C++ Windows Forms application?

I did search in the toolbox window to find ReportViewer control in Visual Studio 2022
and I did try to add new items but I could not find that tool.

At the end, I could not find that tool to add it to a form in Visual C++.

Comment: The MSDN instructions for the ReportViewer Control say "Step 1. Create a new Windows application using either Microsoft Visual C# or Microsoft Visual Basic."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report Viewer Tool can be used in C++CLR Winform project. (C++CLI needs to be installed in Visual Studio installer) Report Viewer is not installed by default. You need to install it by NuGet Manager.

After testing, the reportviewer v 2015 can be used in VS 2022 C++  CLR .NetFramework empty project(add Winform item).

`Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common` can be insalled in C++ project.
But  `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winform.dll` cannot be installed.

You need to create a C# .NetFramework Winform project-> install Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winform.dll.

Then  [add the control to C++ project's toolbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16#add-the-control-to-visual-studio-toolbar).
Right-click in anywhere in the toolbox and then select Choose Items....

> On the .NET Framework Components, select Browse.
>
> Select the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll or
> Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll from the NuGet package you
> installed.
> Blockquote
>
> The new control should display within the toolbox.

[image]

Comment: First think, let me thank you for your answer. but still i have problem with C++ and that tool, when i did try to add the tool: visual studio gave me this message:

Comment: first part of the message: ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
Failed to create component 'ReportViewer'.  The error message follows:
 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Comment: second part:    at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.Reset()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer..ctor()
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: So you would be please tell me what i should you, is it good to edit that line in the regedit or there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install  `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common` related  NuGet package for your C++   project? And make sure the version is consistent with reportviewer

Comment: thank you again, i did create an empty project .net framwork in c# and i installed Microsoft.ReportViewer.Runtime.Common v2015 , version 12.0.2402.15 and the tool is in toolbox, and i did do that twice after deleting every thing and start over as you said ,the thing is first time i did worked on c# and not on C++ but in second time i can see in c# the tools but i can not add it, even i did follow the steps you did write them to me

Comment: Try adding Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common dll reference for your C++ project:  Right click your project-> add -> reference: browser. Then select the  dlls  in  nuget package-> lib folder. There are three dlls:  `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll` `Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll` `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll`.  After adding reference, save,reopen the Visual Studio solution.

Comment: i did it after i reinstall visual studio 2022, my friend thanks to you , but my problem now is that the tool do not works in c++ like when i add it to form in c# so do you have solution to that, i am very thankful even if you do not have a solution. have a nice day

Comment: If you don't mind, you could accept the answer to change the thread's status to Answered. `the tool do not works in c++ like when i add it to form in c#` It is another question. You can post a new thread to attract more attention. I will inform you if there are any updates.

Comment: look my friend , i am new here and there is a lot of thing i do not know so would you please telling me how to do:(If you don't mind, you could accept the answer to change the thread's status to Answered) and then i will ask a new question. thanks again

Comment: There should be a  ['✔'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rbcr.png)   aside my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

adding Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common dll reference for your C++ project: Right click your project-> add -> reference: browser. Then select the dlls in nuget package-> lib folder. There are three dlls: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll. After adding reference, save,reopen the Visual Studio solution